# How to set ruby to use wkhtmltopdf of Unix distribute instead of gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, qt, wkhtmltopdf

I want to run ReportMailer which use wkhtmltopdf in generating a report but I got this error after run it:

> The switch --print-media-type, is not support using unpatched qt, and will be ignored.wkhtmltopdf: cannot connect to X server 
>   Errno::EPIPE: Broken pipe

after I search from the Internet,I found that a gem of wkhtmltopdf is too old that why it try to connect X server.

the version of Wkhtmltopdf of my CentOS is 0.11.0 whilte the GEM of wkhtmltopdf is 0.1.2.

I try to link Wkhtmltopdf from /usr/bin to /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547/bin but I still get the same error

Can you tell me there is another way to let ruby use Wkhtmltopdf from other source instead of its gem?

the version of ruby and rails are 1.9.3p547 and 3.1.12 respectively

Comment: Have you tried install the newest version of `wkhtmltopdf` from official page: http://wkhtmltopdf.org/downloads.html?

Comment: @blelump        yes. I installed the latest version of it to my machine. wkhtmltox-0.12.1-1.x86_64